# How to pass array pointer to a function by reference in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, reference, pass-by-reference

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void populateArray(char* line, char** cmd){
    printf("INPUT LINE: %s\n", line);
    char *  token    = strtok (line, " ");
    int n_spaces = 0, i;

    /* split string and append tokens to 'cmd' */

    while (token) {
      *cmd = realloc (*cmd, sizeof (char*) * ++n_spaces);

      if (*cmd == NULL)
        exit (-1); /* memory allocation failed */

     *cmd[n_spaces-1] = token;

      token = strtok (NULL, " ");
    }

    /* realloc one extra element for the last NULL */

    *cmd = realloc (*cmd, sizeof (char*) * (n_spaces+1));
    *cmd[n_spaces] = 0;

    /* print the cmd */

    for (i = 0; i < (n_spaces+1); ++i)
      printf ("cmd[%d] = %s\n", i, cmd[i]);
}    

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char *cmd1 = NULL;
    char * line = "ls -l";
    populateArray(line, &cmd1);
}
```

I know that C is pass by value but is there anyway to emulate it to pass by reference? I need to pass cmd1 to populateArray(char* line, char** cmd) as a reference. I did some research and to pass by reference in C, it seem like I need to do something like this:
I tried but still cant make it work for the array pointer.

```
void byreference_func(int* n){
    *n = 20;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i = 10;
    printf("before the call the value of i is %d\n", i);
    byreference_func(&i);
    printf("after the call the value of i is %d\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: Error code

```
anon@turing:~/csce3613/assign3$ gcc gg.c
gg.c: In function âpopulateArrayâ:
gg.c:6:24: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
gg.c:17:23: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
gg.c:19:13: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
anon@turing:~/csce3613/assign3$ ./a.out
INPUT LINE: ls -l
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: The C language always passes an array by pointer.  So what is the actual question?

Answer (score 0):

`cmd1` is an array. Arrays cannot be reallocated. You can only use `realloc` on a null pointer, or a pointer returned by a previous call to a `malloc` family function.

Instead you will need to do :

```
int main() 
{
    char *cmd1 = NULL;
    populateArray( line, &cmd1 );
}
```

and then inside your function, change `cmd` to `(*cmd)`.  It is exactly analogous to your `int` example, except everywhere you have `int` in that example you need to change it to `char *`.  You correctly write `*n = 20;` in your int example but then you forget to do that in your real code.

BTW if you are always going to `free` before returning , then you are not really populating an array, and.

Comment: When I try to add char *cmd1 = NULL, it give me error: 'NULL' undeclared (first use in this fuction)

Comment: include `stdlib.h` . You will need `stdlib.h` to do `malloc` anyway.

Comment: I have edited my code. Can you have a look at it? Do I have to use malloc instead of realloc? Also really appreciate for helping.

Comment: You are putting `*cmd` instead of `(*cmd)` in the function

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find the declaration of `line` in your code snippet.
May it be part of your troubles? Can you also add the error that you are getting?

Comment: It was part of my big project so i forgot to put it in the post but line is there. Suppose char *line = "ls -l -a"; will edit the post.

Answer (score 0):

When you do
`char * line = "ls -l -a";` your `line` is actually a `const char *`, not a `char *`

You should do

```
char *line = strdup("ls -l -a");
```

Or do

```
char line[] = "ls -l -a";
```

( this works, read here [What is the difference between char s[] and char *s?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s-in-c))

`strtok()` tries to modify your `line` so it cannot be a `const char*`

And I don't do `char *cmd1[64];`
I do

```
char **cmd1 = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*));
cmd1[0] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 64);
```

Here is the working code : http://pastebin.com/TTsTpdgU

Comment: Do **NOT** cast `malloc`. `char **cmd1 = malloc (sizeof (char *));` is sufficient and prevents accidents...

Answer (score 0):

All strings in C are referenced by pointers (addresses), therefore you are passing the address of the string in every function call using `char *` as the parameter definition. There is no need to pass it as `char **` a simple `char *` will do. To return the value to main, simply declare `populateArray` as `char *` and return a pointer to `cmd1`.

Next as indicated, you are declaring `line` as a constant string literal. In order to make use of it in the way you are, it should be declared as an array of characters. (e.g. `char line[] = "ls -al"`).

As for your program logic, you are making things a bit difficult reallocating for every char you add. It is far easier to use a couple of functions already providing in `string.h`, namely `strcat`. Here is an example. (Note there are many, many different ways to do this, but allocating `cmd` with `calloc` instead of `malloc` initializes a string of NULL chars which makes `strcat` a snap and insures the resulting string is always null-terminated.)

**Updated (I didn't like the first one)**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define CMDSZ 256

char *populateArray (char *line, char *cmd) /* declare as 'char *' and return pointer */
{
    printf ("\nINPUT LINE: %s\n\n", line);

    char *token = strtok (line, " ");
    int i = 0;

    cmd = calloc (CMDSZ, sizeof (cmd));  /* allocate command string to CMDSZ         */

    while (token)                        /* split string and append tokens to 'cmd'  */
    {
        if (strlen (cmd) > 0)            /* if not first command add space           */
            strcat (cmd, " ");

        strcat (cmd, token);             /* add token to cmd    */

        token = strtok (NULL, " ");      /* get next token      */
    }

    for (i = 0; i < (strlen (cmd)); ++i)        /* print each character in cmd */
        printf ("  cmd[%d] = %c\n", i, cmd[i]);

    printf ("\n  cmd: %s\n\n", cmd);            /* print final command         */

    return cmd;
}

int main () {

    char *cmd1 = NULL;
    char line[ ] = "ls -l -a -x -y -z";

    cmd1 = populateArray (line, cmd1);  /* return a pointer to cmd1                 */

    printf ("In main():\n\n  cmd1: %s\n\n", cmd1);

    if (cmd1) free (cmd1);              /* free memory allocated in populateArray   */

    return 0;
}
```

**Note:** `int main(....)` is an integer function -- it should return a value.

**output:**

```
$ ./bin/poparray

INPUT LINE: ls -l -a -x -y -z

  cmd[0] = l
  cmd[1] = s
  cmd[2] =
  cmd[3] = -
  cmd[4] = l
  cmd[5] =
  cmd[6] = -
  cmd[7] = a
  cmd[8] =
  cmd[9] = -
  cmd[10] = x
  cmd[11] =
  cmd[12] = -
  cmd[13] = y
  cmd[14] =
  cmd[15] = -
  cmd[16] = z

  cmd: ls -l -a -x -y -z

In main():

  cmd1: ls -l -a -x -y -z
```